# java.lang.AssertionError: Instance must be configured before use

Tags: android, vimeo, android-tv, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I am trying to integrate **Vimeo API** into an Android App (Android TV App in specific).

I followed the documentation offered by Vimeo [vimeo-networking](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#client-credentials%20grant) but I kind of got lost.

I am getting this error when I run my app:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Instance must be configured before use
```

My whole project is in the following  [Github repository](https://github.com/mezdn/AUB_TV_APP/tree/mediaplayer)

Comment: check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38534220/10460905)

Comment: I've actually done that.